# Problem opening an image using imread with Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, imread

I am trying to follow a tutorial in the Deep Learning for Dummies book.

I am getting an error message when trying to open an image (using imread) that I have downloaded on Google Colab.

The error message:

```
OSError: Cannot seek back after getting firstbytes!
```

[Here is the code on Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1W_5w_MeTLUn3ZCY4hUf_STg4OIWk3c9_); I'm sure it's a trivial thing, but I'm not sure where the error is coming from. Any help appreciated

Comment: i don't have any experience with these stuff, but from error you get, it seems `imread` expects first argument to be filename, but you're passing content of file(`string`) to it (`imread(img_file.read())`). try passing name of the img file to it. also if you're writing exact codes in the book, it's versioning problem. so you can install older version of `imread`, or try to adopt changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the skimage.io documentation [here](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.io.html#skimage.io.imread):
[image: imread documentation]
we can see that the argument of imread() must be the string of a filename and not an object (like `archive.open(filename)`)